# Add Custom Value Besides Price Recently Viewed Products

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

Recently viewed products data is showing using Knockout, How can I add my custom dynamic value (PHP value) besides price as shown in image?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find the responsible JS component and overwrite it as per your need.

Comment: I am searching for the same but unable to find the JS component and HTML template file, to override. Any clue?